# Handle rejection of passport.authenticate() function

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I have a router like this:

```
/* get user info */
router.get('/info', authenticate(), function (req, res) {

  models.User.getUserById(req.user.id, function (result) {
    if (result) {
      var user = result.dataValues;
      res.json({
        success: true,
        data: user,
        message: 'Get user info success!'
      })
    } else {
      res.json({
        success: false,
        message: 'User does not exist!'
      })
    }
  })
});
```

the authenticate() function is like this:

```
/* ensure authentication */
var authenticate = function () {
  return passport.authenticate('jwt', {
    session: false
  });
}
```

If user logged in, the router would go to function(req, res). But what if user has not logged in yet ? How can I return to client a message if user has not logged in ? Can I put a callback to `passport.authenticate()` ? If I can, what is the parameters of this callback ?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Docs](http://passportjs.org/docs), you can add a failure redirect URL and a failure flash message like this :

```
var authenticate = function () {
  return passport.authenticate('jwt', {
    session: false,
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: 'Invalid username or password.'
  });
}
```

Or if you want a custom callback :

```
var authenticate = function (req, res, next) {
  return passport.authenticate('jwt', function (err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) {
      // code if failed here
      return res.redirect('/login')
    }
    req.logIn(user, function (err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username)
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: for the custom callback, the usage is `router.get('/info', authenticate(), function (req, res) {` or `router.get('/info', authenticate(req, res, next), function (req, res) {` ??

Comment: the first one. adding the parameters in the definition.